# Asp.net without reloading the page to change dropdown list to Display a Image

Tags: asp.net

My Script Is

```
   function changeType(photoChoice) {
        document.getElementById('images').src = photoChoice;

    }
```

My Code is

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:changeType(this.options[this.options.SelectedItem].value)" runat="server" >
     <asp:ListItem >-----Select-----</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="~/Image/wedding-cake.jpg">wedding-cake</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="~/Image/Wedding-Cake_heart-cake.jpg">Wedding-Cake_heart-cake</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="~/Image/Whimsical-wedding-cake.jpg">Whimsical-wedding-cake</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div>
<img src="" id="images" alt="Sample Image" width="300px" />
```

The dropdown Select not display the Image. I have an image in Local Folder only.The Listitem value passed to the function.The ListItem value is a image name and path.
How to show the My local Image without reloading the Page.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source? I think that onchange="javascript:changeType(this.options[this.options.SelectedItem].value)" is not even rendered!

Comment: I alter that source    onchange="javascript:changeType(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)   ...But the Image not displayed..